# Removing redundant values in SSRS report group

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, cumulative-sum

I am developing an SSRS report with the following dataset. There is a filter for 'Period'. It is a multi-select filter. Data is grouped by 'Account' field. I need to display Total Expense for each group (which was easy). I also need to display 'Budget' on the same group level. The problem is the budget data is redundant - see below.

Say for the first group (Account=100 AND Period=201301), `Sum([Budget])` would generate 200, which is not true. I can use the Average function which helps if user selects only one Period from the filter. If they select multiple values (e.g. 201301,201302) then the average will be (100+100+150+150)/4=125, which would be wrong because it has to be 100+150=250. I don't want to average among all rows in the returned dataset.

```
ID Account Period  Expense Budget
1  100     201301  20      100
2  100     201301  30      100
3  100     201302  10      150
4  100     201302  40      150
5  200     ...................
```

So, how do I write an expression to make this happen? 
A dirty workaound would be to eliminate redundant values in the Budget column so I can safely use `Sum([Budget])` w/o worrying about duplication. The updated dataset would look like this:

```
ID Account Period  Expense Budget
1  100     201301  20      100
2  100     201301  30      NULL
3  100     201302  10      150
4  100     201302  40      NULL
5  200     ...................
```

Please advice for either approach.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way is to use the [`FIRST()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159861%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) aggregate function.

```
=FIRST(Fields!Budget.Value, "MyAccountGroupName")
```

There are some situations where this won't work. Then you need to move the logic to your query as you describe or you can get fancy with embedded code in your report.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow your "dirty workaround" approach.  You might possibly be able to achieve the result just inside SSRS with some fancy calculations, but it will be totally obscure.